# Avoid that an absolute positioned element push the boundaries of the page width

Tags: css, position

I have an absolute positioned div with an image inside it. It is positioned using top and left, and the width of the element is relative, I am using percentages. I am using Bootstrap as responsive framework.

The trouble is, that I can not avoid horizontal scroll, either computer and smartphone is doing horizontal scrolling.

I thought that in absolute positioning this doesn't affect. But it is making the viewport bigger so the horizontal scrolling is appearing.

I have not idea what to do to solve this, or where to start.

Comment: Absolute positioning doesn't affect other elements but the browser still has to let you be able to scroll to bring it into view **unless you tell it not to**. `overflow-x:hidden` on the body is usually enough to fix this.

Comment: However, questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello @Paulie_D this worked just for the desktop, I'm still having the problem on mobile, I am testing it on android chrome

Comment: Here is the code I have until now: (http://www.sirkell.com/demos/test-mds-01) As you can see, it solved in desktop, but in mobile, specialy in android chrome, it still appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this 'meta' tag in your  :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

and then your  will look more or less like this :

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
    <title>Menu Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
```

Comment: Hello, this is what I have: `<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: can you provide more html and css code, otherwise it is hard to think what might cause this

Comment: Hello Atul, here is a link where I uploaded the code. Cheers!
(http://www.sirkell.com/demos/test-mds-01)

Comment: Abiel, I edited the meta tag in my answer after initial-scale=1 you have to add user-scalable=no. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Good News!!, it worked, now it works with mobile too. What ´user-scalable=no´exactly do?

Comment: It prevents the browser to try and resize the window and fit in all the content(like a zoom in effect).

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll be taking to futures sites. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

You can put

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

on the `body` tag.

This avoids horizontal scrolling by mistake caused by absolute positioned elements somewhere.